# Can I create temporary proxy internet-connection for application debugging?

Tags: c#, web, proxy

I create desktop c#-application than connects with my server. All works perfectly. But some my clients try to use my app in companies that have internet-connection for employees throught Proxy connection, and my app don't works there. I want to understand where is my mistake, but I can't debugging it because there is direct-connection on my machine and I don't have access to my client's machines.
So my question: can I create proxy-connection on my machine, temporarily, for debugging my app? Any firewalls, or virtual machine than will have not direct internet connection. Thanx!

And some code:

```
    private static string SendRequest(SettingsStorage s, string line, string url)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        if (s.Proxy != ProxyType.No)
        {
            if (s.Proxy == ProxyType.Manual)
            {
                WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy(s.ProxyServer, s.ProxyPort);
                if (s.UseProxyPassword)
                {
                    myProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(s.ProxyUsername, s.ProxyPassword);
                }
                else
                {
                    myProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                }
                request.Proxy = myProxy;
            }
            else if (s.Proxy == ProxyType.Auto)
            {
                request.Proxy = System.Net.WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
            }
        }
        //some code...
    }
```

Comment: Is TLS with a certificate being used for Authentication? Did code recently start to fail?  TLS 1.0/1.1 was scheduled to be obsoleted five years ago.  Finally in June Microsoft pushed a Security updated that disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 on server and force TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3 to be used.  So when companies installed the Security Update lots of applications broke.  It is possible the gateway had the security update pushed but not the proxy server.  So internal the code is working while outside it is not.

Comment: My code failed here: `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();`, it throw 407 error.

Comment: One comment, when I create WebProxy I enter ProxyAddress, it is IP, but it is local network IP (for example 192.168.0.1), but I think WebProxy try to find this IP in the Internet, maybe is it my problem?

Comment: Do the clients that fail have other applications that work through the Gateway?  since your code works at some clients and not others I think it is a configuration error in the client network.  I would try to use default credentials and not a username/password.  The failure may be due to windows rejecting the username/password.For security purposes some companies only use the default credentials which take the users login and verify with an internal password server.The authentication is done encrypted using windows encryption which is more secure than sending an unencrypted Network Credential.

Comment: It is best to talk to MIS person at company to find out best way of getting to proxy server.